# SupportMapFragment vs MapFragment performance-wise

Tags: android, performance, supportmapfragment, difference, mapfragment

Are there any differences between [SupportMapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html) and [MapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html)?
In the reference it says that you should only use MapFragment when you target Android API level 12 and higher, but are there any other differences? Is one of them faster?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Are there any differences between SupportMapFragment and MapFragment?

One begins with the word "Support". :-)

Beyond that, `MapFragment` inherits from `android.app.Fragment`, which `SupportMapFragment` inherits from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

> In the reference it says that you should only use MapFragment when you target Android API level 12 and higher

More accurately, you use `MapFragment` with an `Activity` (using native API Level 11+ fragments) and you use `SupportMapFragment` with a `FragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity` (using the fragment backport).

> are there any other differences?

Since the Play Services SDK is closed source, the only way to know that reliably is to get a job at Google so that you can examine the source code.

> Is one of them faster?

They should be near clones of one another. I have not heard of any reports of performance differences.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `MapFragment`, since it extends `android.app.Fragment`.
and `android.app.Fragment` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment).